# Guardar lo seleccionado en un modal y enviarlo junto a la información de mi formulario

Tags: angular, typescript

Buenos días comunidad programadora, tengo una duda que no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Tengo un formulario el cual envío, el detalle es que por requisitos del usuario un listbox que tenia en mi formulario ahora lo pasaron a un modal y este input ya no lo tengo dentro del formulario pero para abrirlo lo llamo dentro del formulario.

Mi duda/pregunta es, se puede enviar lo seleccionado de ese input que esta en modal y fuera de mi formulario junto al resto de datos que llene previamente en el formulario?

```html
        <!-- Dialog nuevo proyecto -->
        <p-dialog [(visible)]="dialogProyecto" [style]="{width: '80%','min-height':'95%'}" [breakpoints]="{'960px': '75vw', '640px': '100vw'}" [modal]="true" class="p-fluid" [maximizable]="true">
            <p-header>
                <i class="pi mx-2 font-bold" [ngClass]="bandModifi ? 'pi-pencil' : 'pi-plus-circle'"></i>
                <span>{{ bandModifi ? 'Modificar proyecto' : 'Registrar proyecto'}}</span>
            </p-header>
            <ng-template pTemplate="content">

                <p-divider align="center">
                    <span class="p-tag text-sm">Datos de la institución</span>
                </p-divider>

                <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Institución</label>
                        <p-dropdown
                            [filter]="true" 
                            filterBy="razon_social" 
                            [showClear]="true"
                            [options]="instituciones" 
                            optionLabel="razon_social" 
                            optionValue="id" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_institucion"
                            placeholder="Selecciona institución">
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Proyecto</label>
                        <input 
                            pInputText 
                            type="text" 
                            class="uppercase"
                            placeholder="Ingresa un proyecto" 
                            required autofocus [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty' : submitted && !m_proyecto}"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_proyecto"
                        />
                        <small class="ng-dirty ng-invalid" *ngIf="submitted && !m_proyecto">Campo requerido.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Estatus</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="value"
                            [options]="estatus" 
                            placeholder="Estatus" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_estatus"
                        >
                            <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                                <span [class]="'multiselect_estatus_proyectos Proyecto_' + option.value">{{option.nombre}}</span>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Introducción (BD)</label>
                        <textarea 
                            pInputTextarea 
                            placeholder="Descripción de la problemática o necesidad social a la que se refiere el proyecto de intervención." 
                            autoResize 
                            rows="3" 
                            cols="30" 
                            class="text-justify"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_introduccion"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Objetivo específico (BD)</label>
                        <textarea 
                            pInputTextarea 
                            placeholder="Desglose de intervenciones estratégicas y tácticas con las que se propone modificar la situación detonante de la intervención." 
                            autoResize 
                            rows="3" 
                            cols="30" 
                            class="text-justify"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_objetivo_especifico"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Actividades a realizar</label>
                        <textarea 
                            pInputTextarea 
                            placeholder="Ingrese las actividades" 
                            autoResize 
                            rows="3" 
                            cols="30" 
                            class="text-justify"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_actividades_realizar"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Objetivo</label>
                        <textarea 
                            pInputTextarea 
                            placeholder="Ingrese el objetivo" 
                            autoResize 
                            rows="3" 
                            cols="30" 
                            class="text-justify"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_objetivo"
                            required autofocus [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty' : submitted && !m_objetivo}"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                        <small class="ng-dirty ng-invalid" *ngIf="submitted && !m_objetivo">Campo requerido.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Estudiantes requeridos</label>
                        <p-inputNumber 
                            mode="decimal" 
                            [showButtons]="true" 
                            [min]="0" 
                            [max]="100"
                            placeholder="Estudiantes requeridos" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_estudiantes_requeridos"
                        >
                        </p-inputNumber>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Estudiantes (Pendiente)</label>
                        <!-- Por comenatrios de jorge esta pendiente
                            <p-dropdown
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            appendTo="body" 
                            optionLabel="label"
                            optionValue="label" 
                            placeholder="# Estudiantes" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_estudiantes"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Sector</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            [options]="sector"
                            appendTo="body" 
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Selecciona un sector" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_sector"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Horario sugerido (BD)</label>
                        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Día de la semana y horarios en que se pretende que l@s estudiantes realicen las actividades asignadas." [(ngModel)]="m_horario_sugerido"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-6">
                        <label class="font-bold">Aprendizajes intencionales del proyecto para l@s estudiantes (BD)</label>
                        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Ingrese un aprendizaje" [(ngModel)]="m_aprendizaje"/>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="col-12 md:col-12 flex">
                        <p-accordion>
                            <p-accordionTab header="Agregar ODS y sus metas" [selected]="false">
                                <p-listbox [options]="metasods" [(ngModel)]="m_id_ods_meta" [metaKeySelection]="false" [checkbox]="true" [filter]="true" [multiple]="true" optionLabel="nombre" optionValue="id_ods_meta" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'250px'}" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty' : submitted && !m_id_ods_meta}" >
                                    <ng-template let-metasods pTemplate="item">
                                        <div class="country-item">
                                            <div><span class="font-bold">{{metasods.nombre}}</span> - {{metasods.meta}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ng-template>
                                </p-listbox>
                            </p-accordionTab>
                        </p-accordion>
                    </div>-->
                    <small class="p-error" *ngIf="submitted && !m_id_ods_meta">Campo requerido.</small>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-12 flex">
                        <p-accordion>
                            <p-accordionTab header="Agregar ODS y sus metas" [selected]="true">
                                <div class="flex justify-content-around flex-wrap">
                                    <div class="ods ods_1" (click)="openODSMetas(1)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_2" (click)="openODSMetas(2)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_3" (click)="openODSMetas(3)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_4" (click)="openODSMetas(4)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_5" (click)="openODSMetas(5)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_6" (click)="openODSMetas(6)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_7" (click)="openODSMetas(7)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_8" (click)="openODSMetas(8)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_9" (click)="openODSMetas(9)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_10" (click)="openODSMetas(10)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_11" (click)="openODSMetas(11)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_12" (click)="openODSMetas(12)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_13" (click)="openODSMetas(13)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_14" (click)="openODSMetas(14)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_15" (click)="openODSMetas(15)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_16" (click)="openODSMetas(16)">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ods ods_17" (click)="openODSMetas(17)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </p-accordionTab>
                        </p-accordion>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p-divider align="center">
                    <span class="p-tag text-sm">Datos de dirección</span>
                </p-divider>

                <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Estado</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown"
                            [filter]="true" 
                            filterBy="nombre" 
                            [showClear]="true"
                            [options]="estado"
                            appendTo="body" 
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Selecciona estado" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_estado"
                            (onChange)="getChangeAdres(1)"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Municipio</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown"
                            [filter]="true" 
                            filterBy="nombre" 
                            [showClear]="true"
                            [options]="municipio" 
                            appendTo="body"
                            optionLabel="nombre"
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Selecciona municipio" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_municipio"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">SM / Región</label>
                        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="SM / Región" [(ngModel)]="m_region"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">C.P.</label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            pInputText 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_codigo_postal"
                            pKeyFilter="num" 
                            [maxLength]="5"
                            placeholder="Ingrese C.P." 
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Calle</label>
                        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Calle" [(ngModel)]="m_calle"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Teléfono</label>
                        <p-inputMask 
                            id="telefono" 
                            autofocus 
                            placeholder="Teléfono" 
                            mask="(999) 999-9999" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_telefono"
                        >
                        </p-inputMask>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p-divider align="center">
                    <span class="p-tag text-sm">Datos del proyecto</span>
                </p-divider>

                <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid grid">
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Personas beneficiadas</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [options]="personasbeneficiadas"
                            appendTo="body" 
                            optionLabel="rango" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="# beneficiados"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_personas_beneficiadas"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Modalidad</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [options]="select_modalidad" 
                            appendTo="body"
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="value"
                            placeholder="Modalidad"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_modalidad"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Apoyo</label>
                        <input pInputText type="text" placeholder="Apoyo" [(ngModel)]="m_apoyo"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label  class="font-bold">Fecha inicio</label>
                        <p-calendar 
                            [showIcon]="true" 
                            [showButtonBar]="true" 
                            placeholder="Fecha" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_fecha_inicio"
                        >
                        </p-calendar>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Duración</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            [options]="duracionproyecto" 
                            appendTo="body"  
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Duración" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_duracion"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-3">
                        <label class="font-bold">Idioma</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            [options]="idiomas" 
                            appendTo="body"  
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Seleccione idioma" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_idioma"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Sexo</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            [options]="select_sexo"
                            appendTo="body"  
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="value"
                            placeholder="Seleccione sexo"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_sexo"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
                        <label class="font-bold">Programa educativo</label>
                        <p-multiSelect 
                            [options]="programaeducativo" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_programa_educativo"
                            defaultLabel="Seleciona programa educativo" 
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            display="chip"
                            appendTo="body" 
                        >
                        </p-multiSelect>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-3">
                        <label class="font-bold">Clasificación</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [options]="clasificacionproyecto"  
                            appendTo="body"
                            optionLabel="nombre"
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Seleccione clasificación" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_clasificacion">
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-3">
                        <label class="font-bold">Tipo de proyecto</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [options]="select_tipo_proyecto"
                            appendTo="body"  
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="value" 
                            [(ngModel)]="m_tipo_proyecto"
                            placeholder="Selecciona un tipo">
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-5">
                        <label class="font-bold">Asesor principal</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            [filter]="true" 
                            filterBy="nombre" 
                            [showClear]="true"
                            [options]="asesores"
                            appendTo="body"
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="id"
                            placeholder="Selecciona asesor"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_id_asesor_principal"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Total de horas</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            [options]="select_total_horas"
                            appendTo="body" 
                            optionLabel="nombre" 
                            optionValue="value"
                            placeholder="Total de horas"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_total_horas"
                        >
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-2">
                        <label class="font-bold">Horas a la semana</label>
                        <input type="number" pInputText placeholder="Hrs" min="5" max="20" step="5" onKeypress="event.preventDefault();" [(ngModel)]="m_horas_semana">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-8" [ngClass]="bandModifi ? 'md:col-8' : 'md:col-12'">
                        <label class="font-bold">Observaciones</label>
                        <textarea 
                            pInputTextarea 
                            placeholder="Ingrese las observaciones" 
                            autoResize 
                            rows="3" 
                            cols="30" 
                            class="text-justify"
                            [(ngModel)]="m_observaciones"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field col-12 md:col-4" *ngIf="bandModifi">
                        <label for="validatenovalidate" class="font-bold">Validar proyecto</label>
                        <p-dropdown 
                            class="position-fixed-dropdown" 
                            appendTo="body"  
                            id="validatenovalidate" 
                            [options]="validadoNovalidado" 
                            optionLabel="label" 
                            optionValue="value" 
                            [(ngModel)]="propDownValidar" 
                            (onChange)="onChange()" 
                            placeholder="Selecciona">
                        </p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="field" *ngIf="rechazotextarea && bandModifi">
                    <textarea 
                        pInputTextarea 
                        placeholder="Agregar un comentario" 
                        autoResize 
                        rows="3" 
                        cols="30"  
                        class="text-justify"
                        [(ngModel)]="m_comentario_rechazo"
                    >
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
                <button pButton pRipple label="Cancelar" icon="pi pi-times" class="p-button-danger p-button-sm" (click)="hideDialogProyecto()"></button>
                <button pButton pRipple label="Guardar" icon="pi pi-save" class="p-button-primary p-button-sm" (click)="saveProyectos(bandModifi)"></button>
            </ng-template>
        </p-dialog>



<!--Panel de ODS -->
        <p-dialog [(visible)]="dialogPanelODS" [modal]="true" [style]="{width: '50%'}" [breakpoints]="{'960px': '75vw', '640px': '100vw'}" [draggable]="false">
            <p-header>
                <i class="pi pi-list mx-2 font-bold"></i>
                <span>Metas de <label class="text-blue-600">{{this.text_ods}}</label></span>
            </p-header>
            <p-listbox [options]="metasods" [(ngModel)]="m_id_ods_meta" [metaKeySelection]="false" [checkbox]="true" [filter]="true" [multiple]="true" optionLabel="meta" optionValue="id_ods_meta" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'auto'}" [ngClass]="{'ng-invalid ng-dirty' : submitted && !m_id_ods_meta}" >
                <ng-template let-metasods pTemplate="item">
                    <div class="country-item">
                        <div>{{metasods.meta}}</div>
                        <!--<div><span class="font-bold">{{metasods.nombre}}</span> - {{metasods.meta}}</div>-->
                        <!--<app-uni-listado-panel-ods-metas></app-uni-listado-panel-ods-metas>-->
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-listbox>
            <ng-template pTemplate="footer">
                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-times" class="p-button-danger p-button-sm" (click)="dialogPanelODS = false"></button>
                <button pButton pRipple icon="pi pi-check" class="p-button-primary p-button-sm" (click)="dialogPanelODS = false"></button>
            </ng-template>
        </p-dialog>
```

son dos modales donde en el primero tengo mi formulario y el segundo modal tengo el input, como le hago que al seleccionar datos del segundo modal(input listbox) se guarde cuando el de en guardar en el primer modal??

Comment: Sin saber cómo montas la modal ni cómo haces absolutamente nada... cómo pretendes que podamos ayudarte?? En principio nadie te impide leer los datos que pongas en la modal y guardarlos en cualquier otro componente, adjuntándolos luego al resto. Te recomiendo que si vienes a preguntar aquí tengas claro que necesitas proporcionar un [mre] o al menos dar los detalles de la implementación concreta que tienes, porque no somos adivinos, somos programadores.

Comment: Adjunte el código amigo, es que estaba desde el celular., pero ahi explico lo que requiero, pasar lo seleccionado del segundo modal al primero y guardar todo desde el primer formulario